# Microsoft Reports Expressions ( <br/> )

Tags: report, expression

Hi Folks i just want to know how can i make a 
 or a "/n" inside of an expression of Microsoft reports

i need to print the result ( for example )

Lab: lab something 
name: name something 
Minimum ammount: $12356, % of discount: 5%

and i have this so far

```
="Laboratorio:"& Fields!NombreProveedor.Value &
"Nombre Oferta: " & Fields!NombreOferta.Value & 
"Monto Minimo: " & Fields!MontoMinimo.Value & "% de descuento " & Fields!Descuento.Value
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using System.Environment.NewLine

```
="First Line" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Second Line"
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA new line is achieved by vbNewLine or vbCrLf:

```
"text1" & vbNewLine & "text2" ...
```